# Part of filename to the CSV file using Perl

Tags: perl, csv, filenames

Having the following input files: `Green_*.csv`, `Red_*.csv`, `Blue_*.csv`, `Yellow_*.csv` how to extract name of the color. I'm trying the following code:

```
sub putInColumn {
    my $filename = getFilename(@_);
    my @name = split '_', $filename;
    if ( $name[0] eq 'Green' )    { return 'Green'; }
    if ( $name[0] eq 'Red' )   { return 'Red'; }
    if ( $name[0] eq 'Blue' ) { return 'Blue'; }
    if ( $name[0] eq 'Yellow' )   { return 'Yellow';}
    return 'error';
}
```

...but I get error. What I want to achieve is to put the color name inside this csv file.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `print $filename;` for some basic debugging

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
my ($color) = ($filename =~ m/^(\w+)_.*\.csv/i);
```

Note the parenthesis around $color - I'm using LIST context from the =~ regex operator to return the groups from the regex into the variable list. So the `(\w+)` will be copied into $color.

This roughly translates to:

```
my $color = undef;
if ( $filename =~ m/^([^_]+)_.*\.csv/i ) {
  $color = $1;
}
```

Comment: The basic error with `\w+_` is that `\w` includes underscore, and the `+` quantifier is greedy, so you will by default always match up until the last underscore in the string. You'd want `[^_]+` instead.

Comment: yeah, i thought so. fixed!

Comment: You should also know that it is not required to initialize a new variable with `undef`.

Comment: I know, i was just being explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
our @arrColors = ('red', 'green', 'etc');

sub putInColumn {
    my $filename = shift;
    $filename =~ /^([^_]+)/;
    my $color = $1;
    return $color if(grep(/$color/i, @arrColors));
    return 'error';
}
```

Comment: @Richard, your example will not work for filenames that have more then one "_": eg - red_some_thing.csv will not match the color name.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider something a bit more dynamic. If all you are matching against are colours, then why not *only* match colours?

```
my @cols = qw(green red blue yellow);
my $rx   = join "|", @cols;
$rx = qr#\b($rx)\b#;
...
sub check_col {
    return $_[0] =~ /$rx/ig;
}
```

Note the use of `\b` around the colour names will avoid partial matches.

Note also the use of the modifiers `/i` which will match case insensitively, and `/g` which in this case will return all the strings matched. A solution like this will allow you some flexibility as to the return value used

```
if (check_col($foo))            # false means no colour found
$found = check_col($foo);       # same thing
$count = () = check_col($foo);  # returns number of colours found
@cols = check_col($foo);        # a list of all colours names found
my ($col) = check_col($foo);    # take first colour found
```